# Cakephp how to import CakeEmail into Shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm on Cakephp 2.4.5, How do i make use of / import  CakeEmail functions so i can use them in my Shell script? I've searched everywhere but can't find an answer. Most examples talk about sending an email from a Controller but not a Shell.

This Shell is executed by a Cron job.

I've tried the following:

```
class EmailShell extends AppShell {

    //App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email'); ///Results in Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'App' (T_STRING),
    //App::import('Component', 'Email');  //Results in Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'App' (T_STRING),
    $tasks = array('Email'); //Results in Error: [0m Task class EmailTask could not be found.

    public function main () {
             //email sending logic here
    }
```

Comment: It's obvious: Your App class can't be found for some reason. Guess your CakePHP core is not found. Run the shell that is included in your app: .\Console\cake email

Comment: @burzum Why would a parser error be related to missing class files? The example shown here is just wrong PHP syntax, the `App::uses()` call can only exist outside of the class construct or inside a function/method, and the `$tasks` variable is missing a visibility keyword, which should result in a parser error too.

Comment: I didn't realize this was outside of a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App::uses statements need to be above the class start:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class EmailShell ...
```

Then you can use it anywhere in this file class:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
...
```